# filter array inside object angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter the results by term but since it's inside an `array` it's being quite hard to reach them with the filters in AngularJS.

```
var test=[

{

"title": "random stuff",

"path": "/random_stuff.html",

"labels": [

  {
    "term": "viewed",
    "probability": 0.083
  },

  {
    "term": "firefox",
    "probability": 0.083
  },

  {
    "term": "cookies",
    "probability": 0.083
  },

  {
    "term": "times",
    "probability": 0.055
  },

],

}
];
```

HTML :

```html
<input class="looking" type="text"  ng-model="data.keywords"/>
<li ng-repeat="se in searchCtrl.data.pages | orderBy : '-views' | filter: ??" >
```

the data.keywords come from here:

```
var id=$routeParams.teamId;
var context=this;

context.data = {
    pages:[],
    keywords:id,
    isLogged:false
};
```

Because I need the first results to be showed from the `ID` in the URL.

Comment: Is this the suture of `pages` the same as the test array?

Comment: the test array came from a document  and the pages i initialize in the controller

Comment: on what property do you want to apply the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the angularjs documentation:

```
friendObj in friends | filter:{$: 'your filter'}
```

> A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array
>
> Note that a named property will match properties on the same level
>   only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same
>   level or deeper.

View the `expression` section:
[filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search" />
    <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="page in list.pages | filter: {$: search}">{{page.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = {
    pages: [{
        "title": "random stuff1",
            "path": "/random_stuff.html",
            "labels": [{
            "term": "viewed",
                "probability": 0.083
        }, {
            "term": "firefox",
                "probability": 0.083
        },

        {
            "term": "cookies",
                "probability": 0.083
        }, {
            "term": "times",
                "probability": 0.055
        }, ],
    }, {
        "title": "random stuff2",
            "path": "/random_stuff.html",
            "labels": [{
            "term": "viewed",
                "probability": 0.083
        }, {
            "term": "firefox",
                "probability": 0.083
        },

        {
            "term": "cookies",
                "probability": 0.083
        }, {
            "term": "my name",
                "probability": 0.078
        }, ],
    }]
};
}]);
```

Please see working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1j5fnrd6/

Type 'my name' and you will see the filter being applied on random stuff2

Comment: already use that but dindt work the most similiar i found with my problem was this http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUuACS2Aa5vEqxqlK04O/angular-js-filtering-nested-array-in-controller.html but since my 'query' is data.keywords im not being able to implement it  :\ im trying to find a new way